# ModelForm and Model validation playing together

Tags: django, validation, model, modelform

I have the following Model :

```
class Advertisement(models.Model):

    slug = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, blank=True, editable=False)

    advertiser = models.ForeignKey(Advertiser)
    position = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=POSITION_CHOICES)
    share_type = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    country = CountryField(countries=MyCountries, default='DE')
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True, blank=True)

    date_from = models.DateField()
    date_to = models.DateField()
```

Based on Advertiser, position, type country and postal code this stores adverisements with range date_from and date_to.

```
advertiser, position, share_type, country and postal_code
```

are coming from the request and are fetched in

```
class CreateAdvertisment(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    # Some usefull stuff

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.advertiser = Advertiser.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        self.share_type = self.kwargs.get('share_type', None)
        self.country = self.kwargs.get('country', None)
        self.postal_code = self.kwargs.get('postal_code', None)
        self.position = int(self.kwargs.get('position', None))
        self.position_verbose = verbose_position(self.position)

        ret = super(CreateAdvertisment, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

        return ret
```

Without any validation for checking date_from, date_to. I can simply do

```
def form_valid(self, form):

    form.instance.advertiser = self.advertiser
    form.instance.share_type = self.share_type
    form.instance.country = self.country
    form.instance.postal_code = self.postal_code
    form.instance.position = self.position

    ret = super(CreateAdvertisment, self).form_valid(form)
    return ret
```

and I am done. Unfortunatly I cannot do this as I do have to check for valid time Frames for the Advertisment to avoid Double Bookings of the same time. I do this in the model with the following :

```
def clean(self):
    ret = super(Advertisement, self).clean()
    print ("country [%s] position [%s] share_type [%s] postal_code [%s]" % (self.country,
           self.position, self.share_type, self.postal_code))
    if self.between_conflict():
        raise ValidationError("Blocks between timeframe")
    elif self.end_conflict():
        raise ValidationError("End occupied")
    elif self.during_conflict():
        raise ValidationError("Time Frame complete occupied")
    elif self.start_conflict():
        raise ValidationError("Start Occupied")
    return ret

def start_conflict(self):

    start_conflict = Advertisement.objects.filter(country=self.country,
                                                  position=self.position,
                                                  share_type=self.share_type,
                                                  postal_code=self.postal_code).filter(
        date_from__range=(self.date_from, self.date_to))

    return start_conflict
```

This works well and I filter out any Conflict for the given period. Problem is that I do not have the instance variables as they are set in view.form_valid() and model.clean() is called by the form validation process.

I do have an chicken egg problem here. I am thinking about setting the requests parameters to the form kwargs in

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(CreateAdvertisment, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['advertiser'] = self.advertiser
    kwargs['position'] = self.position
    ....
```

and then putting them into the form instance in form.**init**()

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    advertiser = kwargs.pop('advertiser')
    position = kwargs.pop('position')
    # .. and so on
    super(AdvertismentCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

For some reasons I do not think this is very pythonic. Does anybody have a better idea? I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that overriding `get_form_kwargs` is ok. If all the kwargs are instance attributes, then I would update the instance in the `get_form_kwargs` method. Then you shouldn't have to override the form's `__init__`, or update the instance's attributes in the `form_valid` method.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(CreateAdvertisment, self).get_form_kwargs()
    if kwargs['instance'] is None:
        kwargs['instance'] = Advertisement()
    kwargs['instance'].advertiser = self.advertiser
    ...
    return kwargs
```

In the model's clean method, you can now access `self.advertiser`.

Comment: thx. kwargs['instance'] is none in my case. Probably because it is a createview. Your proposal would work fine in an UpdateView. I have checked this.

Comment: If `kwargs['instance']` is `None`, then replace it!

Comment: this works fine. Thanks a lot. But would it not be better to already have an valid kwargs['instance'] even in CreateView.get_form_kwargs() ? As this is obviously performed in an UpdateView.

Comment: Yes, it would simplify the code above if the `CreateView` set `kwargs['instance']` to a new model instance instead of `None`

Comment: I think it would be better as I am mixing Information here. The View does not know anything about the model as the form does.

Comment: Instantiating the 'instance' in the view and overriding form.__init__() is like choosing between the "BlackDeath" and "Cholera" as we say in German :-) Your proposal works fine no problem at all. I think to set the instance variables in the __init__() method is less dangerous. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

alasdairs proposal works fine I have the following now :

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(CreateAdvertisment, self).get_form_kwargs()

    if kwargs['instance'] is None:
        kwargs['instance'] = Advertisement()

    kwargs['instance'].advertiser = self.advertiser
    kwargs['instance'].share_type = self.share_type
    kwargs['instance'].country = self.country
    kwargs['instance'].postal_code = self.postal_code
    kwargs['instance'].position = self.position

    return kwargs

def form_valid(self, form):

    ret = super(CreateAdvertisment, self).form_valid(form)
    return ret
```

Of course there is no need to override form_valid anymore. I have just included here in order to display that we do not set the instance fields anymore as this is done in get_form_kwargs() already